# Weird behavior of (^)

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm working on a puzzle solving game in which an exponent function is required, so I define

```
exp' :: Int -> Int -> Int
exp' = (^)
```

Here happens the weird:

```
*Main> exp' 6 25
```

> -8463200117489401856

But

```
*Main> 6^25
```

> 28430288029929701376

I couldn't find any difference between my `exp'` and `(^)` from `ghci`.

Is is a `ghc` bug?

> The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I couldn't find any difference

Yes, there are some differences.

```
:t exp'
exp' :: Int -> Int -> Int

:t (^)
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
```

namely

```
:t (^)
--                           Num    Integral    Num
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a  ->     b    ->  a
```

See? It's about the *type*.

Simply put, `Int` is bounded so it can overflow to negative when exceeding allowed range:

```
> (6::Int) ^ (25::Int)
```

> -8463200117489401856

while `Integer` is unbounded, so does not overflow:

```
> (6::Integer) ^ (25::Integer)
```

> 28430288029929701376

So, to fix it you just change `Int` to `Integer`:

```
exp' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
exp' = (^)
```

You may want to visit https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html for more details about types and Numbers.

Comment: The notation `Num -> Integral -> Num` is source of great confusion for newcomers who do not yet understand typeclasses. I'd avoid it.

Comment: GHC defaults to `Integer` for unspecified `Num` types that are not constrained to be `Fractional`. That seems to be an important part of the answer.